# \r (Carriage return) not working in Command Prompt (CMD)

Tags: java, windows-7, cmd

I have a Java application, and in the app I have this code. (Not mine.)

```
public static void printProgBar(int percent) {
    StringBuilder bar = new StringBuilder("[");

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if (i < (percent / 2)) {
            bar.append("=");
        } else if (i == (percent / 2)) {
            bar.append(">");
        } else {
            bar.append(" ");
        }
    }

    bar.append("]   " + percent + "%     ");
    print("\r" + bar.toString());
}
```

As you can clearly see, I have a carriage return. The only problem is, when I run it in command prompt, the "\r" disappears, but it doesn't do it's job, go back to the start of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would clear the previous value that you're written using some other methods. It would clear the data written in the current line only.

For example

```
int bar = 2;
print("Data: \r" + bar.toString());
```

Would print out this

```
Data: 
2
```

'Data: ' would be in the first line, `\r` would start a new line and write the next data there. I don't see any other data that you wrote before you used this string manipulator.

If you're confused how, see this code example I tested:

[image]

Secondly all the manipulators starting with `\` are disappeared at execution. They're not written. But commands are executed depending on the next character.